# Shortest path algorithm using dictionaries [Python]

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, dijkstra

This is my first question and actually my first time trying this but I read the rules of the questions and I hope my question comply with all of them.

I have a project for my algorithm subject, and it is to design a gui for dijkstra shortest path algorthim. I chose to use python because it is a language that I would like to master. I have been trying for more than a week actually and I am facing troubles all the way. But anyways this is good fun :)!

I chose to represent my directed graph as a dictionary in this way :

```
 g= {'A': {"B": 20, 'D': 80, 'G' :90}, # A can direct to B, D and G
'B': {'F' : 10},
'F':{'C':10,'D':40},
'C':{'D':10,'H':20,'F':50},
'D':{'G':20},
'G':{'A':20},
'E':{'G':30,'B':50},
'H':None}  # H is not directed to anything, but can accessed through C
```

so the key is the vertice and the value is the linked vetrices and the weights. This is an example of a graph but I was planning to ask the user to input their own graph details and examine the shortest path between each two nodes [start -> end] The problem is however that I don't even know how to access the inner dictionary so I can work on the inner paramteters, and I tried many ways like those two:

```
for i in g:
    counter = 0
    print g[i[counter]]     # One
    print g.get(i[counter]) # Two
```

but the both give me the same output which is: (Note that I can't really access and play with the inner paramters)

```
{"B": 20, 'D': 80, 'G' :90}
{'F' : 10}
{'C':10,'D':40}
{'D':10,'H':20,'F':50}
{'G':20}
{'A':20}
{'G':30,'B':50}
None
```

So my question is, could you please help me with how to access the inner dictionaries so I can start working on the algorithm itself. Thanks a lot in advance and thanks for reading.

Comment: Dictionnaries can be access with dictionnary[ 'value' ]; because it is a key-value pair. Welcome to Stack Overflow and I highly respect those who reads the rules. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `for` loop will iterate over the keys of a dictionary, and by using the key, you can fetch the value that is associated to the key. If the value itself is a dictionary, you can use another loop.

```
for fromNode in g:
    neighbors = g[fromNode]
    for toNode in neighbors:
        distance = neighbors[toNode]
        print("%s -> %s (%d)" % (fromNode, toNode, distance))
```

Note that for this to work, you should use an empty dictionary `{}` instead of `None` when there are no neighbors.

Answer (score 6):

This is actually not so hard, and should make complete sense once you see it.  Let's take your `g`.  We want to get the weight of the `'B'` connection from the `'A'` node:

```
>>> d = g['A']
>>> d
{"B": 20, 'D': 80, 'G' :90}
>>> d['B']
20
>>> g['A']['B']
20
```

Using `g['A']` gets us the value of the key in dictionary `g`.  We can act directly on this value by referring to the `'B'` key.

Answer (score 1):

I guess these give you some ideas:

```
for dict in g:
     print dict.get("B","")

for dict in g:
     print dict.keys() #or dict.values()

for dict in g:
     print dict["B"]
```